# How to identify several matching column values to select row and assign value from anothe table to new column with python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to use python to match values of 3 columns from a dataframe to another dataframe and get values from another column in the matching datframe. How do i loop through my dataframe to select the columns to match with the other dataframe and extract the values from the column i want? The matching conditions are columns a,b and c should be the same values.

This is my dataframe [df1]:

[image]

This is the other datframe[df2]:

[image]

This is the result I want to achieve[df3]:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What are your matching conditions? We need more information over here

Comment: The matching conditions are columns a,b and c.

Comment: in `df1` row 3, you've got ita-arg-sen, but in `df2` you've got ita-arg-rsa, but they match anyways in `df3`. Is that a typo ?

Comment: i'm sorry about that. it was a typo. fixed it now.

Comment: You should add data as text, will be easier for us to grab them an try a solution. Please be clearer about your matching conditions. "Coumn a, b, c" is too vague. Should be an exact match? To provide these info, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57434210/edit) your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough with this:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=['a','b','c'], how='inner')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do is to either [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join) OR [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the columns. Use the following [links](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) to satisfy your query as per your required conditions, also refer to some [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_merging_joining).

```
new_df = df2.merge(df1, on=['a','b','c'], how='inner')
# use how='inner' when you want intersection
# use how='outer' when you want union
```

Comment: Links can break, it's best to provide the contents of or summary for the links in your answer text.

Comment: made the required changes! @ifly6

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like the following instead of merge:

```
dft = pd.concat([df1, df2.iloc[:, :3]])
df = df2.loc[dft[dft.duplicated()].index]

print(df)
     a    b    c    d
0  fra  chi  nga  can
1  wal  bra  rsa  usa
4  ita  arg  sen  jam
```